# WebSockets - one or many?

Tags: websocket, tomcat7

I'm playing around with WebSockets for fun, running Tomcat on the backend.  If I have several streams of data I'd like to share with the client, is it better to have one WebSocket per stream or to multiplex them over one shared WebSocket?

It certainly seems easier to have one WebSocket per stream.  I don't need the advanced logic on the client and server to funnel all data into one pipe, and I don't need any overhead in my data format to indicate the source/destination of each frame.

But are there any downsides to using several WebSockets (5-10) on one client page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to allow a lot of multiple simultaneous users, you should minimize the numbers of connections per user, because the number of connections a TCP/IP server can have open at the same time is not unlimited. The number of simultaneous connections is limited in the webservers config, by the operating system and last but not least by the architecture of the IP protocol itself (there are only 2^16 ports).

Comment: Good point.  Also, browsers like chrome limit the number of concurrent connections as well!

Comment: While my particular use-case only expects a handful of users at max, scaling issues is a great point and a clear reason to share a websocket rather than have multiple dedicated websockets.

Comment: WebSocket connections use port 80 as stated [WebSocket Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) "The communications are done over TCP port number 80, which is of benefit for those environments which block non-web Internet connections using a firewall." 
Limited number of port can't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard rumors (but never actually tested) that some browsers may throttle rapid creation of Websocket connections from the same tab/page. If it's true it's to discourage malicious Javascript from trying to use WebSockets to do port scanning. However, apart from that there shouldn't be any issue.

However, since WebSockets is message based (rather than raw streams), it wouldn't be that difficult to mux/demux traffic over one connection. You could add a single character to the beginning of each message to indicate which stream (or if you are sending/receiving JSON maps then just add another field to each message).